# How i can create this type of Progress Bar in react native with graddient support

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, react-native-charts-wrapper

[image]

How can i create this progress bar with 80% circle and multiple gradient colors support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library called `react-native-svg-path-gradient` for this to work you'll also need `react-native-svg`.

You can provide multiple **colors** and have **rounded edges**. It does however need you to provide a `d` prop for the path.

```js
import GradientPath from "react-native-svg-path-gradient";
import { Svg } from "react-native-svg";

<Svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="-2 -2 295 256">
  <GradientPath
    d={
      "M55.5,237.2c-23.5-23.3-38.1-55.6-38.1-91.3C17.3,75,74.8,17.5,145.7,17.5C216.5,17.5,274,75,274,145.9  c0,35.7-14.6,68-38.1,91.3"
    }
    colors={["#EA8279", "#E8C579", "#8DD660", "#E8C579", "#EA8279"]}
    strokeWidth={35}
    roundedCorners
  />
</Svg>
```

Comment: How we can reduce the progress size for example i want to become this progress circle to half or 60 percent where i need to change?

Comment: You can visit this website; [svg-path-visualizer.netlify.app](https://svg-path-visualizer.netlify.app/#M55.5%2C237.2c-23.5-23.3-38.1-55.6-38.1-91.3C17.3%2C75%2C74.8%2C17.5%2C145.7%2C17.5C216.5%2C17.5%2C274%2C75%2C274%2C145.9%20%20c0%2C35.7-14.6%2C68-38.1%2C91.3) which helps you visualize what is going on with the path. Unfortunately my knowledge is to limited on svg's to help you further. This is however a great question: **How to grow a svg path?**